# Google Maps doesn't show in IE7

Tags: google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to display a simple map but it doesn't work in IE7 (nothing is shown and also the div does't take any place at all).

it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I haven't tried any other versions of IE

the template is Jade, but it shouldn't be a problem to understand (.class and #id)

```
div.pull-right(style="width: 450px")
            div.well.well-small(style="width: 450px;")
                div#map-holder
                    div.map#map_canvas
```

this is the map:

```
script
        function initialize() {
            var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(#{location.lat}, #{location.lng});
            var mapOptions = {
                center: loc,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: loc,
                        map: map,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
        }
```

CSS

```
#map-holder img {
max-width: none;
}

.map{
    width:450px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid Javascript:

```
var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(#{location.lat}, #{location.lng});
```

Comment: as I said, its a Jade template, those are template variables which are rendered to values

Comment: So what does the generated javascript look like?

Comment: `<script>function initialize() {
    var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(32.703086210361, 35.192083804844);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: loc,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
        
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: loc,
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
}</script>`

Comment: what javascript do you have that calls the `initialize` function?

Comment: `<body onload="initialize()">`

Comment: Do you need to change your CSS from `.map` to `#map_canvas` ?